# Retrieve corresponding row array of active cell from another sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm attempting to transpose my script from gathering an array from a column to gathering an array from a row instead.  Unfortunately, during the process, I've managed to garble it up pretty well.  I can get the right column, but can't seem to get the right row.

```js
  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 2 && activeCell.getRow() > 1){

    activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearContent().clearDataValidations();

    var item = itemDVss.getRange(activeCell.getRow(),activeCell.getColumn(),itemss.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var itemIndex = item[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) + 2;

    if(itemIndex != 0){

      var itemValidationRange = itemDVss.getRange(itemIndex,3,itemDVss.getLastColumn());
      var itemValidationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(itemValidationRange).build();

      activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(itemValidationRule);

    }
  }
```

The script should locate the active cell in the "Estimate" sheet and return the corresponding values from the "Items" sheet (offset by +1 column).  So when in cell Estimate!B11, the script should return the row array from Items!C11 to the last column.

[Estimate Master Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Za3a9d3hKJCMAxy72sIRH9L61wLwvBw02Fwj_9E_z-4/edit#gid=2018079146&range=B3)

[dynamicDropDowns.gs](https://script.google.com/d/1oz6GOXEA22_ghSyDqV-cp8BnEhsMGjBlJ5XcSQ4kB3lAh2OR6d-7JmAI/edit?usp=sharing) row 34

Comment: It's pretty easy to flatten a column with [Array.map() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is "easy" when you're just beginning to learn it.  At any rate, I got it working by changing

```js
var itemValidationRange = itemDVss.getRange(itemIndex,3,itemDVss.getLastColumn());
```

to

```js
var itemValidationRange = itemDVss.getRange(activeCell.getRow(),3,1,itemDVss.getLastColumn());
```

May not be the best method, but it works!